# Python3 で、`del`文が排除されなかったのはなぜですか？

Tags: python

Python3 では、`print`文が排除されました。
`print`は、プログラムの構造に影響を与えないので、文ではなく関数である、というのはもっともだと思います。

しかし、なぜ `del` は文のまま残ったのでしょうか？
`del`の逆の操作である「代入」が関数ではなく文だからでしょうか？

個人的には、`del`文もまた排除されるべき対象だったように思います。
このままだと、`del` は関数としても文としても書ける (`del(a)` と `del a`) ので、「同じことは同じ書き方」のPythonの流儀から外れているように思います。
なぜでしょうか？

Comment: `del (a)` は関数ではなく、`del` 文に `(a)`、つまり括弧でくくった a を渡しているだけじゃないでしょうか?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`del`の機能は関数では実現出来ません。
delが関数ならば、`del(a)`とした時`del`へ渡るのは変数`a`が評価された後の"値"であって"a"という変数名ではありませんから。

Lispのような言語ではこういった事も関数と同じ見た目の構文（マクロ）で行なう事が出来るようですね。
その方が一貫性があってよい、という意見もあるかと思います。
しかし、Python界隈は「違う機能には違う構文があるべき」という方針なのでしょう。

Comment: 逆に文ならなぜ実現できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 関数の場合「引数式は全て呼び出し前に評価する」というルールがありますが、それは「関数」という物の目的に合わせて言語の設計をそうしているだけです。他の構文（文なり式なり）はまた各々の目的がありますから、都度ルールを定める事にしている、というのは説明になりませんでしょうか。「インタプリタは全て知っている」という言い方で正しいと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。関数は仮引数(parameter)をとり、文では実引数(argument)をとるから、という考えに至りました。間違っているかもしれませんが関係あることないこと考えたのは1) Pythonは他の多くの言語と違って変数は変数そのものではなく、あるオブジェクトに束縛(bind, bound)された名前に過ぎない。2) `del`するのはこの名前であって、オブジェクトそのものではない。3) 関数の仮引数もまた名前に過ぎない。4) 参照渡しと似ているようだが（特にミュータブルオブジェクトの時）、仮引数に他のオブジェクトを束縛することも可能なのだから参照渡しとは異なる。5) 仮引数に束縛されたオブジェクトから実引数の名前を確実に知る方法はない（消した回答の失敗。スタックフレームで得られたソースコードをパースするとか無理矢理やればできるけど） 5) 名前のないオブジェクトは適宜ガベージコレクトされる。